# How to use koa-request with koa v2?

Tags: node.js, koa

I want to send a `GET` request inside this middleware and wait for the response then complete the middleware:

```
const koa = require('koa')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const request =  (require('koa-request'))
const app = new koa()
const router = new (require('koa-router'))
const respond = require('koa-respond');

app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(respond());

router.post('/webhook/', async (ctx,next)=>{
    let options = {
        url:'https://.....'
    }
    let data = await request(options)
    console.log(data)
})
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log("app started")
    console.log("Listening to ",port)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/request/request-promise , that use await you only need that library return promise or you can wrap "koa-request" in Promise.